# How to get grid from EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE event?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have two grids and I want to bind `EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE` for the same function.

```
    self.gridA.Bind(EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE,self.OnCellChange)

    self.gridB.Bind(EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE,self.OnCellChange)
```

How can I distingish in the event which grid invoked it?

```
def OnCellChange(self,evt):
       grid = .....? 
evt.Skip()
```

The action done by the function is the same on both grids... I just needs to know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for every event, the object (window) originating the event is retrieved by calling `GetEventObject` (see [`Event` object](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Event.html#Event.GetEventObject)).

```
grid = evt.GetEventObject()
```